# Examples of functions that are in $L^p(X,\mu)$ but not in $L^q(X,\mu)$, where $1< p < q <\infty$ for each $p$ and $q$?

Tags: lp-spaces

It is known that if $\mu(X) < \infty$, we have the inclusion $L^q(X,\mu) \subset L^p(X,\mu)$ when $1<p<q$. This implies $L^p$ is a "bigger" space than $L^q$. (Or is it a bad idea to think of them as big and small spaces?)

Can we have some examples of functions that "lie" between the big and small $L^p$ spaces, i.e., $f \in L^p$ but $f \notin L^q $ for **each** $p$ and $q$, $1<p<q<\infty$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the finite measure space $(0,1]$, I might consider $x^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha > 0$.  This is in $L^p$ if $\alpha p < 1$ and is in $L^q$ if $\alpha q < 1$.  I.e., if $p < \frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $q < \frac{1}{\alpha}$, respectively.  You should have no challenge finding an *interesting* $\alpha$ for each choice of $p < q$.  For instance, for $p=2$, $q=3$, try $\alpha = 2/5$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Let $f=x^{-1/r}$ for some $r \in (p,q)$. Then $\|f\|_p^p = \int_0^1 x^{-p/r}\mathop{dx} \le \int_0^1 x^{-(1-\epsilon)}\mathop{dx}<\infty$ but $\|f\|_q^q = \int_0^1 x^{-q/r} \mathop{dx} \ge \int_0^1 x^{-(1+\epsilon)} = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Are there examples other than $f = x^{-\frac{1}r}$, $r\in (p,q)$?